# Navigation with ContentPresenter MVVM Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

So I'm trying to make a simple navigation using MVVM in Xamarin forms, and people suggested that I used the control template with a content presenter.
So far so good.

I made the control template, but I'm not sure how to bind content presenter to my buttons so it changes when I click them.

App.Xaml

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ThemeMaster">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="App name" BackgroundColor="Blue"></Label>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                  Content="{Binding changeContentCommand}">

                </ContentPresenter>
                <Button Text="Click me" Command="{Binding changeContentButtonCommand}"></Button>

            </StackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

When I open the program contentpresenter starts showing the mainPage as it should, but what should I write in MainViewModel.cs too change contentpresenter too lets say LeaderBoardPage?

Comment: How you are associating mainPage with `ContentPresenter`, via x:Name?

Comment: why you are not creating the custom control?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create different `ControlTemplate` for your different content.